# sed second occurrence of a string - for all lines in external file (Linux)

Tags: linux, sed, while-loop

I have a file that has duplicate values in column 2 that need to be renamed. There are ~8k duplicate values (in file **list.of.duplicates**) throughout the ~5m line file (**with.duplicates**).

### Data set inputs:

**with.duplicates**

1       rs143225517     0       751756  C       T

1       rs146277091     0       752478  A       G

1       rs3094315       0       752566  G       A

1       rs149886465     0       752617  A       C

1       **rs3131972**       0       752721  A       G

1       **rs3131972**       0       752721  AT      G

1       rs3131971       0       752894  T       C

1       rs61770173      0       753405  C       A

1       rs2073814       0       753474  C       G

1       rs2073813       0       753541  A       G

1       rs12184325      0       754105  T       C

**list.of.duplicates**

rs3131972

rs4310388

rs7529459

rs905135

rs9786995

rs12065710

rs6426404

rs12759849

rs6603823

### Code I tried

This does exactly what I want - but inefficiently and for only one substitution

```
sed -i '0,/rs3131972/! s/rs3131972/qrs3131972/' with.duplicates
```

But I can't figure out how to iterate through the entire list of duplicate values

```
i=0 
while ((i++)); 
read -r snp 
do 
sed -i '0,/${snp}/! s/${snp}/q${snp}/' with.duplicates 
done < list.of.duplicates
```

I've found partial answers throughout the site but none that get everything together into an efficient script.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Looking for a solution in Linux or R

edit:

**Desired output**

1       rs143225517     0       751756  C       T

1       rs146277091     0       752478  A       G

1       rs3094315       0       752566  G       A

1       rs149886465     0       752617  A       C

1       **rs3131972**       0       752721  A       G

1       **qrs3131972**       0       752721  AT      G

1       rs3131971       0       752894  T       C

1       rs61770173      0       753405  C       A

1       rs2073814       0       753474  C       G

1       rs2073813       0       753541  A       G

1       rs12184325      0       754105  T       C

Comment: See edited post! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, awk can handle this on its own. You don't need a loop.

```
awk '(FNR==NR) { d[$1]; next }
     ($2 in d) && !(++d[$2]-2) { $2 = "q" $2; delete a[$2] }
     1' list.of.duplicates with.duplicates
```

> Can it be modified to instead of adding the "q" to the second column of the second occurrence, to add the q to the second column of the longer line?

It can be but this wouldn't be as efficient as the above.

```
awk '(ARGIND==1) { d[$1]; next }
     (ARGIND==2) {
         if ($2 in d) {
             if ($2 in r) { if (length(r[$2]) > length()) d[$2]++; delete r[$2] }
             else { r[$2] = $0 }
         } next }
     ($2 in d) && !(++d[$2]-2) { $2 = "q" $2; delete d[$2] }
     1' list.of.duplicates with.duplicates with.duplicates
```

Comment: This is great - it works exactly as needed! Can it be modified to instead of adding the "q" to the second column of the second occurrence, to add the q to the second column of the longer line?

Comment: Thanks @oguzismail!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is using the `uniq` command to filter the file on the second field and returning the lines that are non-unique.

(if the duplicates are not on adjacent lines, you will sort the file first by the second field to ensure they are)

Given your data in `inputs`, you can report the non-unique lines with:

```
$ uniq -D -f1 -w10 inputs
1 rs3131972 0 752721 A G
1 rs3131972 0 752721 AT G
```

**Explanation**

While `uniq` is generally used to identify unique values, it can also be used to identify all repeated values, e.g.

- `-D` print all duplicate lines
- `-f, --skip-fields=N` avoid comparing the first N fields
- `-w, --check-chars=N` compare no more than N characters in lines (adjust as needed)

Combining the options will print all duplicate lines skipping the 1st field and comparing only 10 characters beginning with the 2nd field.

You may have to tweak the width by one or two and adjust any other options needed to cover your entire input file. Don't forget the note about sorting if the duplicate lines are not already adjacent to each other.

Comment: Thanks - I used 

`awk '{print $2}' with.duplicates | uniq -c | grep -v '^ *1 ' `

to get the list of duplicates.

The original file (with.duplicates) needs to stay in order without sorting.